# Is it possible to solve an underdetermined system of linear equations? (Preferably with SymPy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to write a script to balance chemical equations. I'm testing it with the photosynthesis reaction:

CO2 + H2O -> C6H12O6 + O2

As a Python expression:

```
a0*(C+2*O) + a1*(2*H+O) = b0*(6*C+12*H+6*O) + b1*(2*O)
```

As a SymPy expression:

```
Eq(a0*(2*H + O) + a1*(C + 2*O), 2*O*b1 + b0*(6*C + 2*H + 6*O))
```

or

```
a0*(2*H + O) + a1*(C + 2*O) - (2*O*b1 + b0*(6*C + 2*H + 6*O))
```

'H', 'C', and 'O' are SymPy symbols representing the atoms.

'a0', 'a1', 'b0', and 'b1' are SymPy symbols representing the molecule coefficients.

How can I solve for 'a0', 'a1', 'b0', and 'b1' so that the coefficients of 'H', 'C', and 'O' are equal on the left and right side of the reaction? Also, there are an infinite number of solutions so how can I specify the lowest positive solution?

Comment: the lowest positive one will be the one when all factors have no common divisor. So a simple loop can get you there from any solution. And you can get any solution by fixing one parameter to 1 then solving for others, possibly obtaining fractional values that you can easily scale to a global factor to get rid of all denominators.

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution space is 1d and the system is homogeneous you can read the smallest integer solution off the nullspace of the matrix describing the system. Here is how to get the nullspace using sympy (the rows of the matrix correspond to C, O, H, the columns to a0, a1, b0, b1):

```
m = sympy.Matrix([[1, 0, -6, 0], [2, 1, -6, -2], [0, 2, -12, 0]])
n, = m.nullspace()
n / functools.reduce(sympy.gcd, n.T)
# Matrix([
# [6],
# [6],
# [1],
# [6]])
```

So the smallest integer solution is a0 = 6, a1 = 6, b0 = 1, b1 = 6